# pygame OOP moving a rectangle

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I'm learning python and I'm currently trying to program a snake game.
I'm an absolute beginner, python is my first programming language and this is my first time trying to do something with OOP.

I know there is already an answer to a similar question but I have too little understanding of the OOP concept to solve my problem with it. 
I need help with my particular problem and code.

```
import pygame

WHITE = (255,255,255)

class init_window:
   pygame.init()

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')


    def draw_snake(self, startx, starty, width, height):
        self.startx = startx
        self.starty = starty
        pygame.draw.rect(self.gameDisplay, WHITE, [startx, starty, width, height])
        pygame.display.update()
        init_window.move_snake(self, self.startx, self.starty)

    def move_snake(self, x_current, y_current):

        FPS = 60
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.x_current = x_current
        self.y_current = y_current

        x_change = 0
        y_change = 0

        x = self.x_current
        y = self.y_current

        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        x_change = -5
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        x_change = 5
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        y_change = -5
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        y_change = 5

            newx = x + x_change
            newy = y + y_change
            init_window.draw_snake(self, newx, newy, 50 , 50)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(FPS)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    width = 800
    height = 600
    window = init_window(width, height)
    window.draw_snake(width//2, height//2, 50,50)
```

When I run the code the rectangle 'stretches' in the direction of the key I'm pressing and after a few seconds I get a very large number of errors and the program stops.

What do I need to change in order to get it working?

Comment: Its the recursion depth exceeded. You have structured your code in such a way that `move_snake` calls itself. After 1000 iterations it will exit with a `RunTimeError` exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started.

```
import pygame

WHITE = (255,255,255)

class init_window(object): 

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')


    def draw_snake(self, startx, starty, width, height):

        pygame.draw.rect(self.gameDisplay, WHITE, [startx, starty, width, height])
        pygame.display.update()
        init_window.move_snake(self, startx, starty, (width, height))


    def move_snake(self, x, y, rectsize):

        FPS = 60        
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        rectheight, rectwidth = rectsize

        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                    x_change = 0
                    y_change = 0

                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        x_change = -5
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        x_change = 5
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        y_change = -5
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        y_change = 5

                    x += x_change
                    y += y_change

                    self.gameDisplay.fill((0,0,0))

                    pygame.draw.rect(self.gameDisplay, WHITE, [x, y, rectheight, rectwidth])
                    pygame.display.update()

                    clock.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    width, height = 800, 600
    pygame.init()

    window = init_window(width, height)
    window.draw_snake(width//2, height//2, 50,50)
```

I just took out the recursion that was causing your exit. I hope this achieves what you were looking to do.

Note also it was necessary to clear the screen before each draw `self.gameDisplay.fill`, otherwise the rectangle left a trail around the screen.